# Crear ifstream para lectura de un archivo .csv en C++

Tags: c++, archivo

Tengo un programa en c++ que crea y agrega datos a un archivo .csv, a pesar de que lee los datos no puedo hacer que lo haga de la forma que me hace mas conveniente, para esto intento crear un `std::ifstream` que es necesario para usar `std::getline(ifstream, string, limit)` el asunto es que a la hora de crear el `ifstream` se crea y no da ningun error en el compilador, pero al ejecutar no toma el valor del string que le estoy dando.
quiero crear el ifstream con el valor que me da el `std::getline();`puesto que me da los datos de cada linea por separado y lo quiero usar para despues de cada linea sacar el valor correspondiente a cada columna.

Codigo:

```
for (std::string linea; std::getline(MyFile, linea); )
{
    std::ifstream registro(linea); //quiero crear el ifstream con el valor que me da el getline
    std::string dato;

    for (string dato; std::getline(registro, dato, ',');)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido bien. ¿En un fichero (MyFile), tienes lineas que son nombres de ficheros que quieres ir abriendo de uno en uno creando para ello un ifstream por fichero?

Answer (score 3):

> quiero crear el ifstream con el valor que me da el std::getline();

Esta afirmación no tiene ni pies ni cabeza.

`ifstream` sirve para leer archivos, no para leer valores en memoria. Para realizar esta última tarea puedes usar `stringstream`. Un *stream* pensado para leer valores en memoria:

```
std::stringstream registro(linea);
```

En cualquier caso, el algoritmo te seguirá fallando porque a `registro` le estás dando únicamente una línea (es el resultado de llamar a `getline`), luego la segunda llamada a `getline` te va a devolver todo el contenido de `registro` (solo hay una línea).

Imagino que en este caso lo que pretendías hacer era separar los diferentes campos de la línea, pero para eso debes indicar un caracter separador:

```
std::getline(registro, dato, ';'); // o el delimintador que desees
```